# What is the minimum Kernel version required for Docker 19, 20, 23, 24, 25 and 26?

Tags: docker, version, rhel, rhel7

I have a RHEL 7.9 server with Kernel version 3.10. And I'm trying to figure out if latest version of Docker supports my server.

What is the minimum Kernel version required for Docker 19, 20, 23, 24, 25 and 26? I tried to check release notes, but I can't find info regarding this.